# Cuckoo Filters: Why exactly 7 counts? (As in "limited count" of entity insertion.)

Tags: algorithm, hash, filter, bloom-filter

I've been trying to wrap my head around cuckoo filters these past few days.  I understand that they have advantages over bloom filters in many ways, and generally their use is preferable (if you can use them).

I need counting for the application I am looking for, though.  I can't find information anywhere on why exactly there is "limited counting" in cuckoo filters.  (Although I have heard that the limit is 7.)

Is this a theoretical limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuckoo filters can keep multiple copies of a single key. All of the items have the same hash values, and so they are all inserted into one slot in one of the two possible buckets. When the buckets have size 4, that is 8 total slots.

Generally, attempting to add a key when its possible slots are full is not a problem - one of the keys in its slots is simply kicked out. However, when all the keys are the same, there is no overflow or backup location they can go to.